# How do you pass variables as arguments in a function call within HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, arguments

Using Javascript, I'm trying to run a loop that creates elements with html attributes that when clicked triggers another function and passes variables as arguments.

[HERE'S A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2PFBE/2/)

Ideally in this example Funky() would be called when clicking a letter and log something like: `c word_2` Unfortunately I'm getting either `Funky is not defined` or `c is not defined`  When I run something very similar to this off of fiddle I get `[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLSpanElement]`  How do u properly do this sort of thing?

```
function Funky(letter, word) {console.log(letter + " " + word)} 

var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']
var recollection = "";

for(x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
    recollection += '<p onclick="Funky('+arr[x]+', word_'+x+')">' +arr[x]+ '</p>';
    }
```

Comment: Since your fiddle has `onLoad` selected, all the Javascript is inside an anonymous `window.onload` function, and isn't visible to inline attributes. Try changing that to one of the "No wrap" options.

Comment: I tried that and all the other options, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having it in the onload is an issue.  Plus, you need to add quotes (escaped)

```
    recollection += '<p onclick="Funky(\''+arr[x]+'\', \'word_'+x+'\')">' 
                    +arr[x]+ '</p>';
```

In your fiddle, change to "no wrap-in body" and try it again.

Comment: Ok awesome, it works.  What does "no wrap-in body" mean? And why do u need to add escape quotes?

Comment: If you don't add the quotes around the letter, then JavaScript will interpret the letter as a function name. I'm assuming that you are meaning to pass the letter as a string, not a function.  Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.  Thank you.  Is the way I'm doing this bad practice?

Comment: @Squirrl: The lack of quotes is not simply a matter of bad practice; they're essential.  Without them, the JS interpreter expects them to be a reference name, not a string.  And since there is no variable named, say, `a`, you get an error.

Comment: @CMKanode: That's slightly off; the interpreter will expect them to be a the **name** of something currently in scope, not necessarily a function.  But the essential point is that they won't be treated as a string.

Comment: Would it be a better approach giving all the elements a class name and than using getElementsByClassName to find the parameters for the function call that way?

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you for pointing that out about the unquoted letters being interpreted as a name of something in scope.  I appreciate the correction.

Comment: @Squirrl: I'm not quite sure how that would help.  Passing in the numeric index would be easier than escaping the string parameter.  Or your could look at the techniques in my updated solution.

Comment: @Scott.  That is very helpful and clean.  I wish I had more points to give out.  Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your Fiddle has a reference problem with the function simply because of the way Fiddle is built.

If you move your Funky function into a script tag inside the HTML block you will **[fix that problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/2PFBE/6/)**.

Then you have internal problems.

```
function Funky(letter, word) {console.log(letter);} // skipping "word" for now


for(x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
    recollection += '<p onclick="Funky(\'' + arr[x] + '\');">' +arr[x]+ '</p>';
}
```

That will generate blocks like

```
<p onclick="Funky('a')">a</p>
```

You needed to put the parameter to the function inside quotes.  And I've entirely skipped the `word` parameter, which I don't understand.

But this feels like it might not be the best way to do this in general.

---

### Update

Here's an alternative -- and to my mind cleaner -- way of accomplishing the same thing:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'];

function Funky(idx) {
    console.log(arr[idx] + " " + 'word_' + idx);
} 

$('#list').html(arr.map(function(letter, idx) {
    return '<p data-idx="' + idx + '">' + letter + '</p>';
}).join("")).on('click', 'p', function() {
    Funky($(this).data('idx'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the strings. You also need to add the HTML in the document.ready handler.

```
function Funky(letter, word) {
    console.log(letter + " " + word)
}

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
var recollection = "";

for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    recollection += '<p onclick="Funky(\'' + arr[x] + '\', \'word_' + x + '\')">' + arr[x] + '</p>';
}

$(function () {
    $('#list').html(recollection);
    console.log(recollection);
});
```

But since you're using jQuery, why do you need to use inline handlers like this? Give all the elements a class and bind a click handler to the class.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2PFBE/5/)

Comment: This is working, with the escape.  Is it improper?  Would jQuery be a better approach than this for any other reason?

Comment: jQuery is cleaner because everything gets parsed just once when the Javascript is loaded.

Comment: I'm trying to really understand and learn JS and avoid jQuery for this project.  Could I use `document.ready` and `getElementsByClassName`? Would that be a better approach than the way I'm doing it?

Comment: I assumed you were OK with jQuery because you're already using it for `$('#list').html(recollection)`. You could do without it, you'll just have to loop through all the elements returned by `getElementsByClassName`.